# Wordpress bug with capabilities?

Tags: uploads, media, capabilities

EDIT: aha! It appears to be the "Role Scoper" plugin causing this problem. Deactivating it restored the functionality. Consider this question null.

I've enabled the capability of uploading files for contributors.

However, I found a problem. When the contributor start a brand new post, he will see the "Upload/Insert" icons right above the post edit box.

However, if the contributor saves a draft then comes back later, then those icons will be gone!

I used the "Capability Manager" plugin to modify the contributor capabilities. I'll try another plugin and see if it makes a difference...

EDIT: nope, it doesn't make a difference. THe capabilities are stored in the database, and deactivating plugins leaves the capabilities as they were (they stay modified)...

This appears to be a wordpress bug. I'm gunna file a bug repot...

Answer (score 1):

Activate the plugin again, reset your caps to default. I guess the problem is the plugin - not wp. Maybe it misses to add some capability.

Best would be to try to take a look at the capabilites that are assigned to the different roles.

#### How-to inspect current user data the smart way

Create an account for both roles (admin and contributer) and then `var_dump` their capabilites with something like my old [Current User Deamon Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/your-friendly-current-user-deamon/). Just take a look at the capabilites, diff them and then add everything that's needed per hand.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply Kaiser. The problem is that contributors don't have the upload_files cap by default. I have added that cap to contributors. Adding the upload_files cap made the Upload/Insert icons appear initially (when making a new post), but fails to make the icons appear when editing a draft.

Comment: It actually does seem like a bug with WP because enabling the upload_files cap for contributors should work in all cases (including editing a draft)... Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, never delete your Q. In case this really is a bug (which I doubt) you should only add a tag for the wordpress version and write it in your Q. That's just for the case that the bug doesn't get solved, or someone uses the same version as you and is searching for a solution.

Comment: Why I don't think it's a "bug": Other users can do the same without problems. The sys is built out of capability checks, so I say it's a config issue on your side :)

Comment: Indeed, it was a plugin called "Role Scoper" causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating the "Role Scoper" plugin or any other plugins that could potentially be causing the problem.